# Usar la salida de un comando de linux como parámetro de otro comando como: ls, cd, etc

Tags: linux, bash

A veces tengo que localizar algún directorio, utilizo por ejemplo `which phpstorm` para saber dónde está instalado el ejecutable de ese programa.

Ahora quiero navegar al directorio donde se encuentra el ejecutable usando por ejemplo `cd`, o `ls` para ver el contenido completo del directorio.

¿Hay alguna manera sencilla para recuperar o usar la salida del primer comando para poder utilizarla en el segundo sin tener que teclear todo?

Comment: Es posible que lo que quieras sea un pipe? http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es coger el resultado de un comando y aplicarlo a otro. En tal caso, lo útil es coger este comando y ejecutarlo con `$( )`, aplicando luego ese valor en el comando que quieras:

```
ls "$(which otro_programa)"

cd "$(which lo_que_sea)"
```

Internamente, lo que esto hará es:

```
ls "$(which otro_programa)"  # → ejecuta el `which`
ls "resultado"               # → aplica el resultado a `ls`
```

---

Más generalmente, UNIX funciona con la idea de las *pipes*, que sirven para [concatenar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16892/1674) comandos de manera que lo que dice uno se lo pasa al otro y así sucesivamente.

Ello nos permite por ejemplo tener una serie de pequeñas aplicaciones haciendo entre todas una tarea compleja:

```
sort fichero | tr -s ' ' | grep "hola"
```

<sub>Esto ordenaría un fichero, eliminaría los espacios de más y luego buscaría las líneas en que aparece "hola".</sub>

Comment: Guau, muchas gracias por la respuesta y gracias por el añadido final :)

Answer (score 1):

Con:

```
primer_comando | segundo_comando
```

Esto te permite usar la salida del primero como parámetro de entrada del segundo.

Comment: En este caso particular, `which bla | ls` no funcionaría.

Answer (score 1):

Cada comando que ejecutas en Linux tiene Entradas y Salidas Estandar (stdin, stdout). Significa que lo que emite un comando puede ser redireccionado a otro. (| para filtrado, < y > para volcar o leer el contenido en un archivo y >> para agregar mas contenido a un archivo).

Por ejemplo, para redireccionar la salida de un comando y volcarla a un archivo de texto, basta con ejecutar:

```
$ which phpstorm  > archivo.txt
```

Si Deseas mostrar un archivo y ordenar la salida podrias usar la barra de filtrado, esto redirige el stream.

```
$ ls -la | sort
```

Existe mucha documentacion online. Podrias empezar por este articulo interesante aca:

[Redirecciones y Tuberias en Linux](https://hipertextual.com/archivo/2014/07/redirecciones-y-tuberias-bash/)