# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una función en Bash y pasarle parámetros?

Tags: funciones, bash, shell-script

Tengo actualmente un fichero llamado funcion.sh que contiene una función para Bash:

```
function dimeNombre {
    nombre=$LOGNAME
    echo -n $nombre
}
```

Y otro fichero llamado hola.sh con el siguiente contenido:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "/home/pdelgado/Escritorio/funcion.sh"
dimeNombre "$?"
echo "Hola $1"
```

Necesito que el script hola.sh llame a funcion.sh y que esta le devuelva el nombre de usuario para que hola.sh use dicho parámetro en el echo.

Tengo un lío enorme con esto de usar funciones externas y cómo pasar parámetros de un lado a otro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Bash no hay un `return` al uso como lo conocemos en otros lenguajes. Como la idea que subyace es la de que [la salida de un comando se usa para el siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/194550/83), lo que hacemos es *decirle* qué ha salido. De allí que en las funciones devolvamos cosas con un "echo" o "printf" o lo que sea que devuelve a stdout.

Por tanto, para llamar a `dimeNombre` y recoger su resultado, debes ejecutar el comando y guardarlo en una variable:

```
resultado=$(dimeNombre)
echo "dimeNombre ha devuelto $resultado"
```

Otro ejemplo:

- Definimos la función `dime_nombre`:

  ```
  function dime_nombre { 
      echo "23"
  }
  ```
- La llamamos:

  ```
  $ dime_nombre 
  23
  ```
- La llamamos y lo guardamos en una variable:

  ```
  $ res=$(dime_nombre)
  $ echo "$res"
  23
  ```

Comment: Pero entonces @fedorqui, ¿para qué sirven los parámetros $1, $2...$9?

Comment: @lk2_89 los parámetros `$1` y hasta `$9` son los que das por parámetro al ejecutar un script. Si ejecutas "hola.sh" con `bash hola.sh bbb` te contestará con un "Hola bbb". Después está `$0` que representa la ruta del script que se está ejecutando.